SFMC journey behaviour UpdateDE in email-basedTemplate
I need pointers: I have SFMC journey which is using DE and email based template (in email template amp script I am updating on flag based  field on my payload) as next step I would like to use that flag value in decision element to trigger another follow up email template but before decision element value coming as NULL, wondering why isServiceEmailRequired boolean is NULL as I can it is updated to DE properly (True) as part of UpdateDE?
Basically I would like to trigger second email template based on this value (it seems Journey will not consider previous updateDE update?)
this is amp script UpdateDE code of Order confirmation email Email
enter image description here
I triggered first template based email (order confirmation email) and then I expect amp script code into to updateDE
SET @updateStatus = UpdateDE("MH_OrderConfirmationTest", 1, "OrderNumber", @OrderNumber, "IsServiceEmailRequired", @isServiceEmailRequired, "BookingStatus", @successBooking)

I can see in DE value of isServiceEmailRequired is True setup but in next step I am observing it is NULL.
Basically I want to trigger my next email based template (service email) when isServiceEmailRequired is true only.
Is there any other way to do this?
